# Tengo un codigo que genera un archivo txt pero al momento de visualizar los datos en el archivo están corruptos

Tags: java, archivo, txt

```
public class Imprimir implements Serializable {
      int id;
      String name;
      String department;    

public Imprimir(int id, String name, String department) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.department = department;
      }
    
      public String toString() {
        return "Persona(" + id + "," + name + "," + department + ")";
      }
```

*Se supone que debería mostrarme el código como estoy formulando al agregar ahí abajo*

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ArrayList<Imprimir> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    lista.add(new Imprimir(26989102, "Cristians", "Departamento A"));
    lista.add(new Imprimir(269891022, "Andres", "Departamento B"));
    lista.add(new Imprimir(269891023, "Jose", "Departamento C"));

    FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("C:\\proyectos\\output.txt");
    ObjectOutputStream out= new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
    out.writeObject(lista);
    out.close();

  }
}
```

Pero en lugar de eso me muestra esto en el archivo de texto

```
¬í sr java.util.ArrayListxÒ™Ça I sizexp   w   sr Imprimir¹PXJg„O I idL 
departmentt Ljava/lang/String;L nameq ~ xp›Ò.t Departamento At  Cristianssq ~ 5Ît Departamento Bt Andressq ~ 5Ït Departamento Ct Josex
```

Busco que mi archivo de texto muestre lo siguiente:

26989102,Cristians,Departamento A
269891022,Andres,Departamento B
269891023,Jose,Departamento C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes tener presente que el archivo que estas creando no es un archivo de texto en si , es un archivo binario. Es por eso que te salen un montón de símbolos raros.

En vez de guardarlos como objetos puedes hacer uso [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) en Java es una clase que se usa para escribir datos en forma de caracteres en un archivo..y [BufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) Clase que nos permite escribir texto en un Outputstream, utilizando un buffer para proporcionar una escritura eficiente de caracteres, arrays y strings.

antes de usarlos debes crear `getters` en tu clase,esto para iterar el arrayList y obtener los datos de los objetos guardados

```
public int getId() {
          return id;
      }       
public String getName() {
          return name;
      } 
public String getDepartment() {
          return department;
      }
   


//Remplazar
    // FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\output.txt");
        // ObjectOutputStream out= new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        // out.writeObject(lista);
        // out.flush();
        // out.close();
    
      
    
        FileWriter fileWriter = null;
            try {
              //crea el flujo para escribir en el archivo
              fileWriter = new FileWriter("ubicacion del archivo");
              //crea un buffer o flujo intermedio antes de escribir directamente en el archivo
              BufferedWriter bfwriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
              for (Imprimir p : lista) {
                //escribe los datos en el archivo
                bfwriter.write(p.getId() + "," + p.getName() + "," + p.getDepartment() + "\n");
              }
              //cierra el buffer intermedio
              bfwriter.close();
              System.out.println("Archivo creado..");
        
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
              if (fileWriter != null) {
                try {//cierra el flujo principal
                  fileWriter.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
            }
```